# Format/Style current_user_display_name in WP

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am fairly new to coding and need a little guidance. I am using the following .php:

```
// [current_user_display_name]

function display_current_user_display_name () {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $display_name = $user->display_name;
    return $user->display_name;
}
add_shortcode('current_user_display_name', 'display_current_user_display_name');
```

and would like to style the text with CSS. I'm not sure how to do this, I tried this:

```
.display_current_user_display_name 

{
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:lato;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:regular;
}
```

but it did not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could be the PHP code for creating the WordPress shortcode.
Using this shortcode `[current_user_display_name]` will display an HTML span with the CSS class `user-display-name`.

We only show this if the user is logged in.

```
/**
 * Current user display name shortcode.
 */
function get_current_user_display_name() {

    // Check that the user is logged in.
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();

        return sprintf( '<span class="user-display-name">%s</span>', $user->display_name );
    }

    // If user is not logged in don't return anything.
    return;
}
add_shortcode( 'current_user_display_name', 'get_current_user_display_name' );
```

Below is an example of how to style the CSS class `.user-display-name`:

```
.user-display-name {
    /* CSS code here */
}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Not sure that I understand the difference so I'm reading this a few times.